# Magento 1.9 new color custom option inherit the name of the size existing custom option

Tags: magento

I am new in Magento and need to learn. I have a platform based on Magento 1.9 developed by another developer. i have addeded custom option of color. but there is size custom option already added before. in the frontend, the tile  appear at the bottom of the new color custom option is the size custom option and the validation also inherit the size custom optio. Where can fix this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This link "Know your size" is not native from Magento, the another developer customized this point.

Customization probably was made in this file: /app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

But if you can't find it there, you can use "Ctrl or Command(For Mac) + Shift + F" on your favorite IDE to search for this exactly phrase: "Know your size" and if you can't find yet in this way, it's because he may have done the personalization directly at Magento Admin in CMS->Blocks menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can change requirement of this custom option for admin panel. Entry on editing of this product, and last tab from left are for custom option.